# Unity Board Game AI Causing Memory Leak

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I am creating a board game similar to tic tac toe, and I've created an AI to play that game. The AI is very CPU intensive, so I decided to put it on it's own thread. I'm using this plugin to do multithreading: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15717 .

I have this IEnumerator:

```
static IEnumerator executeAITurn(Turn turn) {
    Vector2[] move = mctsManager.mcts(new State(sections, null, turn), AIIterations)[0, 0].metaData.lastMove;

    yield return Ninja.JumpToUnity;

    input(move, true);

    yield return Ninja.JumpBack;

    Debug.Log("DONE!");
}
```

and I run it using

```
gameManager.StartCoroutineAsync(executeAITurn((AITurn == Turn.X) ? Turn.O : Turn.X));
```

Normally when I run executeAITurn it works normally without problems, but for some reason sometimes when I run it, it does what it's supposed to but in task manager my memory just starts to increase by like 30 mb / sec. The memory increases all the way to 1000 mb and the game gets really slow. When I turn off play mode, the memory sometimes continues to increase or just stops where it is. I have to end Unity through task manager to free the memory.

One thing I've tried is replacing foreach loops with regular for loops and that seemed to help. The rate at which the memory was increasing decreased by a lot(initially it would increase at around 100 mb / sec).

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some of the code involved in executeAITurn:

mctsManager Class: https://pastebin.com/yzeHrY2p

input Function: https://pastebin.com/8f2hzZws

Comment: Did you tried to debug it? Unity has an in-built profiler.

Comment: I just checked the profiler and most of the memory seems to be coming from ManagedHeap.UsedSize (424.9 MB), System.ExecutableAndDlls (301.0 MB) and ManagedHeap.ReservedUnusedSize (163.1 MB). I'm not sure what I should do with this information. Should the reservedUnusedSize be that high?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the multithreading plugin?

Comment: @DavidOliver I haven't. I'll try that now

Comment: Your generateMoves function is calling itself recursively.  You might want to keep track of how deep you get in the recursion and log out to the console if you get to some big number you don't expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the answers to this question really helped me better manage memory. I just thought I'd summarize the big things from each in one question.

First of all, in Robert Livingston's answer he mentions this article: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-garbage-collection-unity-games, which literally covers everything that helped me. I wish I had read that before hand.

Anyways, the three biggest things that helped me were avoiding boxing, clearing lists, and caching (All three of which are mentioned in the article). Trying to avoid boxing also led me to do research on the difference between value-types and reference-types, which led me to change two of my classes to structs, which helped with memory.

The biggest help to memory was probably clearing lists, as they were being created very frequently, but I wasn't clearing them causing a lot of garbage to build up. (This is why I gave the bounty to the person who mentioned clearing lists).

Anyways, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds more like a garbage collection issue. I looked at your code for MCTS and noticed the following.

```
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
```

This was missing from your first code, C# Input functions.
Basically, this is invoking an update function. As you may notice, it says update function is called once per frame. Refer to this https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-garbage-collection-unity-games

I would recommend a cache.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why would I have a Start and Update function inside my input function?

Comment: That article is really nice. Thanks for that. I'm definitely going to try to implement more caching, and clearing the lists as someone else mentioned was also very useful.

Comment: Well, the void Update() and LateUpdate() essentially call for code every frame. This can add quite a bit of unwanted garbage. As an example, if you have an object that isn't even being used or clicked, there is no reason to have that code fire off every frame. The garbage will pile up quick and make for a heavy and slow experience. Glad to hear that helped, best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with memory leaks, you have to be very careful, because every step in your application is important.

For beginners, every loop you have, may cause an increase in memory. 
Try reversing from using loops, to working with dictionary and hash table, it will cost you with 'out-of-order' data, since it is comparing hash codes, but I don't think you need a certain order for your data in the game.

**Clarification:**
*Every list of array that you have, if you know the exact size of your array, use ArrayList. If you use list, switch it to dictionary, if the type of the list is known to you or Hash Table if not. this way you will be able to get the information in a key - value way, which is faster and improves performance.*

Second, try use the Using syntax when ever you instantiate a new object, this will help you implement iDisposable interface to dispose of objects more effectively.

Third, Prevent your code from boxing variables as much as you can! 
boxing means, the process of storing a value type in the heap instead of in the stack, so in the stack you only have a reference to the variable's location.

Fourth, use tools to monitor you code and check for possible memory leaks in your applications. 
There are a lot of tools except for the profiler out there so just search for it and you will find something to help you.

Comment: I'm busy at the moment, but I'll try making these changes later and tell you if it helps. Also can you give me an example of how you could use dictionaries / hash tables in place of a loop. I can't see how they are related.

Comment: I know I already asked you this, but can you please expand on what you said about replacing loops with dictionaries. I've made a lot of changes based on the third tip, which was very useful. The memory leak isn't as bad anymore but it's still noticeable, so I want to do whatever else I can to make it better.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, it only gives general advice that should be given as commentaries. On top of that, some of the advice is simply wrong.

Comment: I suppose it is since the person who asked the question said it did help.

Comment: Not really considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46014039/767890) follow up question.

Comment: assuming that he does use, it will help. You cannot say that it won't because there are objects that do not implement iDisposable.

Comment: An object only needs to implement `IDisposable` if it uses directly or indirectly unmanaged resources it needs to clean up. You seem to think all objects need to implement this pattern which is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First task manager is **not** a valid tool to measure Performance of even [memory demand](http://www.itwriting.com/dotnetmem.php). The figures can be both way to high and way to low. Possibly at the same time.

Secondly, the very nature of the [Garbage Collector](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/286d8c7f-87ca-46b9-9608-2b559d7dc79f/garbage-collection-pros-and-limits?forum=csharpgeneral) makes measuring how much memory is actually used really tricky. The GC will try to run as little as possible. And if it only runs on application closure, that is the ideal case.

If you have excluded that it is any of those two common misconceptions, usually memory leaks in a Managed Runtime mean one thing:
You add something to a Collection (array, List<>, Dictionary<,>) but forget to take it out again. That is the only way a memory leak can happen. In particular GC is there so we do not run into the "I forgot to free memory" problem ever again.

A rarer case is mistakes with [Disposing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx). If you hande umanaged resources directly you should be writing your finalizer first, Dispose second.
If you handle anythign that implements IDisposeable, always also implement IDisposeable even if all your Dispose() does is relay the order to the contained instance. Never relay a Finalize order, that is between that instance and the GC.

Comment: First of all, in response to your first statement, I also ran the profiler in unity and after the ai ran for like 1.5 minutes my total memory allocated was 2.2 GB and pretty much all of it was coming from ManagedHeap.Used Size (1.4 GB)

Comment: Second, if you look at lines 85-113 in my mctsManager script, there's a function involving a List of Section arrays. Also look at line 205 where I use that function. I don't get rid of the the stuff in the List anywhere. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: That is definitley a cause for Memory Leaks. The one way the GC can figure out if a object is unused, is by there being no (strong) reference to it anymore. If there is at least one, it can not collect it anymore then it could the temporary variable in your current function.

Comment: I started clearing the lists once I was done with them, and this helped a lot thanks!